# Understanding the arity parameter of the method Proc.curry in Ruby

Tags: ruby, currying, arity

In the documentation of Ruby's `Proc.curry` method at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Proc.html#method-i-curry, it says:

> curry -> a_proc
>
> curry(arity) -> a_proc
>
> Returns a curried proc. If the optional arity argument is given, it determines the number of arguments. A curried proc receives some arguments. If a sufficient number of arguments are supplied, it passes the supplied arguments to the original proc and returns the result. Otherwise, returns another curried proc that takes the rest of arguments.

I know `arity` means the number of arguments of a function. However, I'm not quite clear how it works here. Can anyone help to explain, please? I've read the examples on the doc, but still confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps walking through a better example might help. Let us start with a simple proc:

```
p = proc { |a, b, c| "a=#{a.inspect}, b=#{b.inspect}, c=#{c.inspect}" }
p[1,2,3]
# "a=1, b=2, c=3"
```

If we call `curry` without the `arity` argument then it is pretty clear what's going on:

```
p.curry          # evaluates to a proc
p.curry[1]       # and a different proc
p.curry[1][2]    # another different proc
p.curry[1][2][3] # "a=1, b=2, c=3" 
p.curry[1,2]     # yet another proc, hooray for procs!
p.curry[1,2][3]  # "a=1, b=2, c=3"
p.curry[1,2,3]   # "a=1, b=2, c=3"
```

So `p.curry` gives us a succession of `Proc`s by supplying values for the arguments until we have enough to evaluate the original `Proc`. Now we start adding `arity` values:

```
p.curry(1)          # some proc
p.curry(1)[]        # some other proc,
p.curry(1)[1]       # "a=1, b=nil, c=nil" 
p.curry(1)[1, 2]    # "a=1, b=2, c=nil" 
p.curry(1)[1, 2, 3] # "a=1, b=2, c=3"

p.curry(2)          # a proc
p.curry(2)[]        # another proc
p.curry(2)[1]       # oh look, a proc, a lovely surprise
p.curry(2)[1][2]    # "a=1, b=2, c=nil" 
p.curry(2)[1, 2]    # "a=1, b=2, c=nil" 
p.curry(2)[1, 2, 3] # "a=1, b=2, c=3"
```

The `arity` argument is setting the effective arity of the curried proc; don't bother looking at the *real* arity – `p.curry.arity`, `p.curry(1).arity`, ... – since it will always be `-1` (i.e. variadic). The result is that `p.curry(1)` is sort of like

```
proc { |a| p[a] }.curry # "change" p's arity to 1 then curry
```

and `p.curry(2)` is sort of like:

```
proc { |a, b| p[a, b] }.curry # "change" p's arity to 2 then curry
```

etc. Keep in mind that just because a (non-lambda) proc has arity `n` doesn't mean that you have to call it with `n` arguments. A proc's arity is more of a suggestion than anything else.

Of course, if you try this chicanery with a lambda then everything goes sideways because lambdas care very much about their arity:

```
λ = ->(a, b, c) {  "a=#{a.inspect}, b=#{b.inspect}, c=#{c.inspect}" }

λ[1]             # ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3))
λ.curry[1]       # a lambda-proc
λ.curry[1][2][3] # "a=1, b=2, c=3" 
λ.curry[1][2, 3] # "a=1, b=2, c=3" 

λ.curry(1)       # ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3))
λ.curry(2)       # ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3))
λ.curry(3)       # a lambda-proc that's just like λ.curry
```